# Error when using multiple Selects in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use multiple Selects in a Procedure but I keep getting an error it says on line 18, I'm kind of new to Stored Procedures so I could use some help as to what I'm doing wrong.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `WeatherRecord`;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE WeatherRecord(IN ID INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE Rid INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE Rdate DATE;
    DECLARE Record DECIMAL(5,2);


DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, High_temp
    FROM Past_weather WHERE High_temp = (
SELECT MAX(High_temp) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '1', 'HH_Temp');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, High_temp
    FROM Past_weather WHERE High_temp = (
SELECT MIN(High_temp) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '2', 'LH_Temp');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, Low_temp
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Low_temp = (
SELECT MAX(Low_temp) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '3', 'HL_Temp');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, Low_temp
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Low_temp = (
SELECT MIN(Low_temp) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '4', 'LL_Temp');
    close c;


DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, High_hum
    FROM Past_weather WHERE High_hum = (
SELECT MIN(High_hum) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '5', 'LH_Hum');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, Low_hum
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Low_hum = (
SELECT MIN(Low_hum) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '6', 'LL_Hum');
    close c;


DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, High_dew
    FROM Past_weather WHERE High_dew = (
SELECT MAX(High_dew) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '7', 'HH_dew');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, High_dew
    FROM Past_weather WHERE High_dew = (
SELECT MIN(High_dew) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '8', 'LH_dew');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, Low_dew
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Low_dew = (
SELECT MAX(Low_dew) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '9', 'HL_dew');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, Low_dew
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Low_dew = (
SELECT MIN(Low_dew) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '10', 'LL_dew');
    close c;


DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, High_ pressure
    FROM Past_weather WHERE High_ pressure = (
SELECT MAX(High_pressure) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '11', 'HH_pressure');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, High_ pressure
    FROM Past_weather WHERE High_ pressure = (
SELECT MIN(High_pressure) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '12', 'LH_pressure');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, Low_ pressure
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Low_ pressure = (
SELECT MAX(Low_pressure) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '13', 'HL_pressure');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, Low_ pressure
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Low_ pressure = (
SELECT MIN(Low_pressure) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '14', 'LL_pressure');
    close c;


DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id,  Wind_max
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Wind_max = (
SELECT MAX(Wind_max) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '15', 'H_wind');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id,  Wind_gust
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Wind_gust = (
SELECT MAX(Wind_gust) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '16', 'H_gust');
    close c;


DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, Rainfall
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Rainfall = (
SELECT MAX(Rainfall) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '17', 'H_rainfall');
    close c;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select Date, City_id, Snowfall
    FROM Past_weather WHERE Snowfall = (
SELECT MAX(Snowfall) FROM Past_weather WHERE City_id = ID) && City_id = ID;
open c;
fetch c INTO Rdate, Rid, Record;

Insert into Weather_records(Date, City_id, Record, Record_type, Record_name)
    values(Rdate, Rid, Record, '18', 'H_snowfall');


    close c;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: do basic debug, remove things until start working and then start adding things again.

Comment: Yea that would be a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-cursor.html):

> A stored program may contain multiple cursor declarations, but  each
>   cursor declared in a given block must have a unique name.

As a side note; cursors are comparatively inefficient compared to the `INSERT-SELECT` queries you could be using. Example....

```
INSERT INTO `Weather_records`(`Date`, `City_id`, `Record`, `Record_type`, `Record_name`)
SELECT `Date`, `City_id`, `High_temp`, '1', 'HH_Temp'
FROM Past_weather 
WHERE High_temp = (
   SELECT MAX(High_temp) 
   FROM Past_weather 
   WHERE City_id = ID
   ) 
   && City_id = ID
;
```

... this replaces the first cursor-insert in your sql proc... **and/but** doesn't ignore if multiple-rows come out of the select (from multiple rows having the same highest temp).

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I could reuse the same cursor name if I closed it and then reassigned it. But also thanks for showing me a better way to write it.

Comment: @CaseyBridges I always declared all my cursors before any "code" in procs, always used handlers, and always iterated over the cursor results; I'm not sure why, but it never even occurred to me you could declare them later (as needed).

Comment: What is the difference in using ` vs ' ?

Comment: ` delimits field names in MySQL, ' is for string values.